# How to delete item from list and not in database in Grails (Archive concept)?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm new to grails ,I'm trying to implement archive in grails.That is When i try to delete an item from list it must delete in list but not in database. And in database a flag would be appear on deleted item in list. 
 Please guide me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have add an `active` boolean field to the domain in question so the object in question can be marked as active or inactive.  You will also have to customize the delete action in the appropriate domain controller so the object is not deleted, because instead of deleting you just want to change the `active` boolean value to `false`.  Then in the list action of the appropriate domain controller, you will have to filter out all inactive objects before listing them.

**UPDATE:**

See code below for a simple explanation on what I am suggesting.

```
//The User domain class
class User {
    String username
    boolean active = true    
}

//The delete action of the User controller
def delete = {
        def userInstance = User.get(params.id)
        if (userInstance) {
            //Here instead of deleting the user, we just mark the user as inactive.
            userInstance?.active = false
            //You may choose to change this message to something that indicates the user is
            //now inactive instead of deleted since the user is not really being deleted.
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), params.id])}"
            redirect(action: "list")
        }
        else {
                flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), params.id])}"
                redirect(action: "list")
        }
}   

//The list action of the User controller
def list = {
        def users = User.findAll("from User as users where users.active=false")
        //Instead of writing "userInstance: User.list()" I filtered out all inactive users
        //and created the "users" object then wrote "userInstance: users". Build in other
        //parameters as you see fit.
        [userInstanceList: users]    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.Please can u explain with example?

Comment: Is there any example or document for this problem?

Comment: search for the term "soft delete"

Comment: Instead of having to filter each query, you can use a hibernate filter (http://www.grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter) to automatically filter all queries. Note that you'll need to use findById() instead of get() because get() doesn't respect the hibernate filter.

Or you might be able to override the get() function like typoknig did with list. Not sure if that's possible.

Comment: @Brad Rhoads That is an option, but the process of using that filter seems like more of a hassle than its worth. If it is an object I'm going to need filtered in many different cases I would just write a service for it. Less code and you don't have to work outside of Grails.

Comment: I have another query I have two classes User And UserItem.They have]  one to one relationship between them.Both tables have the same "username" as primary key. In userItem table, "username"is the primary key and also a foreign key to UserItem table. If i try to delete in User list it must hide User item and also coressponding userItem which belongs to particular item. I tried in many ways but all showing error .Pls solve this problem .

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question, and provide the code for your classes pertaining to your question.  In that way the members of SO will more likely be able to help you solve your problem.